# Consequence of pigeon-hole principle.

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics

I came across the following pigeon-hole type statement in a paper I am reading. Let $0<\epsilon_1\leq \epsilon_2$ be reals. Suppose that $S$ is a finite set and $f,g:S\to [0,\infty)$ are functions such that

1. $\max_{s\in S}\{f(s)\}\leq 1$ and
2. $\sum_{s\in S}f(s)g(s)\geq (1-\epsilon_1)\sum_{s\in S}g(s)$.

Then if $S'=\{s:f(s)\geq 1-\epsilon_2\}$ we have $$\sum_{s\in S'}g(s)\geq (1-\epsilon_1/\epsilon_2)\sum_{s\in S}g(s).$$

The argument given in the article starts with the pretty obvious step
$$(1-\epsilon_1)\sum_{s\in S}g(s)\leq\sum_{s\in S}f(s)g(s)\leq \sum_{s\in S'}g(s)+(1-\epsilon_2)\sum_{s\in S\setminus S'}g(s).$$

The result is supposed to follow from this but I don't see how.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is now just some simple algebraic stuff.

Expanding, you get
$$\sum_{s \in S} g(s) - \epsilon_1\sum_{s \in S} g(s) \leq \sum_{s \in S'} g(s)
+\sum_{s \in S\setminus S'} g(s) - \epsilon_2\sum_{s \in S\setminus S'} g(s)
$$
so you can erase in both sides $\sum_{s \in S} g(s)$ and get
$$\epsilon_1\sum_{s \in S} g(s) \geq \epsilon_2 \sum_{s \in S\setminus S'} g(s) = 
\epsilon_2 \left(\sum_{s \in S} g(s) - \sum_{s \in S'} g(s)\right)
$$
i.e.
$$(\epsilon_2 - \epsilon_1) \sum_{s \in S} g(s) \leq \epsilon_2 \sum_{s \in S'} g(s)$$
and dividing for $\epsilon_2$ gets you the result.

Comment: I was pretty sure it was supposed to be simple. I feel kinda silly for not seeing this.